# Python reorder lists inside lists

Tags: python, list

Hopefully I can explain this well I have a list that is n in length but for this example lets use this.

```
List = [[['a','b','c'], [1,2,3], [7,8,9]],[['e','f','g'], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]]
```

I want to change up all the values to yield

```
List = [[['a',1,7], ['b',2,8], ['c',3,9]], [['f',4,1], ['g',5,2], ['c',6,3]]]
```

so essentially List[0][0], List[1][0], List[2][0] and so on. I have tried a bunch of stuff and I cant quite find the write mix to get this working. any help would be appreciated

I have attempted too many things to count and non of them are particularly valuable so ill leave that out for now.

Comment: What happened to "f" and "g"? Or is this a typo/copy-paste-error?

Comment: You can use numpy: `import numpy as np; print([b.T for b in np.array([[['a','b','c'], [1,2,3], [7,8,9]],[['e','f','g'], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]])])`

Comment: it was a typo! and numpy is rocking its socks off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zip!

```
[[list(x) for x in zip(*sublist)] for sublist in List ]
```

Or, with unequal lengths:

```
[map(None, *sublist) for sublist in List] # Python 2
[list(itertools.zip_longest(*sublist)) for sublist in List] # Python 3
```

If you can be ensured that the sublists are of equal length and tuples would suffice instead of lists, then:

```
[zip(*sublist) for sublist in List]
```

Comment: that works on python 2 only, me thinks

Comment: not enough. `zip` does not produce a list, but a tuple.

Comment: edited per above comments

Comment: OK, but do you check your code? The first line produces `[['a', 1, 7], ['b', 2, 8], ['c', 3, 9], ['e', 4, 1], ['f', 5, 2], ['g', 6, 3]]` on python 3

Comment: part of me knew it didn't make sense to add another `for` statement without another comprehension

Comment: it's alright now, thank you. I had come up with `[list(map(list,zip(*el))) for el in List]`. :)

Comment: ooo, you can even get rid of the first `list` to have: `[map(list,zip(*sublist)) for sublist in List]`

Comment: not on python 3. That was my whole point. No indication was given about the python version used by the OP, so it's always better to cover both (with distinct solutions as in this case or with one that works on 2 and 3)

Comment: thanks for the help! o_o's comment knocked it out like a young veral mike tyson! [map(list,zip(*sublist)) for sublist in List] and this is all in Python 2.7, should have mentioned that.